# opencart cart and checkout error

Tags: opencart, checkout, cart

I installed a new theme, but im having 2 problems there:

1. when I add a product to the cart and click on the cart button, I get ..index.php?route=checkout/cart page not found ( but when there is no product in the cart, it works good)
2. when I choose to register at the check out, fill up everything and click on the next, i get error again (a customer gets confirmation email, i get a registration to my system, byt the website doesnt go on) , when i choose to pay without registration, it works good.

I tried to contact designer of the theme even opencart, but they couldnt fix it. the website is www.obleckovo.sk

I was talking to a developer of the theme, but it looks the theme has nothing to do with that, the theme is compatibile with the opencart version.

I have also tried to change to default theme and there is the same problem, so propably there is a problem at the opencart, we've checked the file with my other eshop ehich is working good and there are not many differences. Opencart support haven't contacted me yet

Thank you for help

Comment: Ask the theme developer for help. We're going to need much more than that!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third-party software (theme) and asker should ask for help it's developer(s).

Answer (score 0):

`/index.php?route=checkout/cart` does not return *Page not found* (404) error, but **Content encoding error**:

> Content Encoding Error
>
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported >form of compression.

This may be solved by turning the compression off (if turned on) in administration: `System` -> `Settings` -> `Edit` -> `tab Server` and somewhere at the end should be an option `Compression level` => setting it to `0` would turn the compression off. **If this is not the case** (compression was turned off already) **then this is a pure HTML problem and it is a problem of the theme** thus contacting and requesting a support from the developer is essential.

I didn't try the second problem but in the case You are explaining only two possible reasons come to my mind: either You are returning (echoing/printing) something in the AJAX request thus the JSON response contains non-JSON content and cannot be parsed (check the NET tab of Firebug when doing this register request and check for the response content when done), or it is a problem of the theme (wrong JS-code part) and then You should again contact the developer.